# Morphism of Shimura varieties and differential equations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, modular-forms, shimura-varieties

Is there a way of constructing a morphism between Shimura varieties using differential equations? Maybe, this looks like a completely ridiculous question, so I think that I should explain the context of this question.

In [this](https://eudml.org/doc/206306) paper, three related ways of constructing a morphism of Shimura varieties (section 3.1-3.3) are introduced. Among them, the second construction uses *realisations of monodromy groups of certain differential equations of second order with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}(z)$ and regular singularities at 0, 1, and $\infty$*. I could not find any reference which explains the way of getting (or, finding) such differential equations. Again, I guess that this may be not enough for getting appropriate answer. I am really sorry for failing to ask well-posed question, but this is all I can do since I could not understand any relation between *differential equation* and *Shimura varieties*.

Anyone who can introduce related references will be really helpful. Thank you very much in advance.